# Fibonacci sequence in python given number n

Tags: python

I have tried to creat a code,that given number n,it will print F[n] (wereas F the function i created in order to calculate the fibonacci number) .But apparently there is something wrong because no matter the input,the result is always 1.Heres is the code:

```
def fib(n):
    a=1
    b=1
    x=1
    for i in range(n):
        a=b
        b=x+b
        x=a
        return a
n=input()
print fib(n)
```

Comment: Indentation matters, move return statement outside the loop.

Comment: Questions like this never cease to amaze me. Did you even try to debug it?

Comment: not working.plus i want every number between 1 and n to print

Comment: Yes, we gathered that it's not working. Try changing bits of it to see if that makes it work. That's quite a key programming technique.

Answer (score 3):

Python is a whitespace sensitive language. The scope of a block of code in Python is determined by the level of indentation so:

```
def fib(n):
    a=1
    b=1
    x=1
    for i in range(n):
        a=b
        b=x+b
        x=a
        return a # <--- the first time you run through the loop you return
```

`return a` is in the for loop as it is indented at the same level as the rest of the for loop. So the first time you run through the loop you reach the `return` statement which leaves the function at that point in time. This is most likely not what you want. You need to take the `return` outside the `for` loop, like so:

```
def fib(n):
    a=1
    b=1
    x=1
    for i in range(n):
        a=b
        b=x+b
        x=a
    return a # <--- now no longer in the loop.
```

Now the loop will run through all of `range(n)` and you can return your result after that.